# Вложенный цикл for дает непонятный результат

Tags: python, python-3.x

Совсем начинающий в python.
Написал такой цикл:

```
count = 0
a = [1,5,3,4,2]
k = 2 
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
        if a[i] - a[j] == k:
            count += 1
            print("i = " + str(i))
            print("j = " + str(j))
print ("count = " + str(count))
```

Результат:

```
i = 1
j = 2
i = 3
j = 4
```

Почему такой результат? Я ожидал:

```
i = 0
j = 1
j = 2
...
i = 1
j = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что [твой код выводит](http://ideone.com/Zj2Xj4) только те индексы, для которых разность равна k.

Чтобы выводить все индексы (хотя, а зачем?), можно сделать так:

http://ideone.com/Y7U40T

```
count = 0
a = [1,5,3,4,2]
k = 2 
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    print("i = " + str(i))
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
        if a[i] - a[j] == k:
            count += 1
        print("j = " + str(j))
print ("count = " + str(count))
```

Comment: да, действительно,  туплю. Привык к скобкам. Здесь их нет